# is it good to install ubuntu and windows on lenovo g510?

Tags: preinstallation

i recently bought lenovo g510(i5,8GB RAM) how to install windows and ubuntu on this without having any crash of os.

Comment: Yes it is, I had my computer setup like this until I found no use for Windows.

Comment: Perhaps this guide will help you http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Answer (score 0):

Nobody guaranties you will have no crashes. However It is well known that to install Windows and Ubuntu alongside is easy enough. If you don't want to recover Linux bootloader, then first install Windows and then Ubuntu.